# How to print lines that don't match?

Tags: perl

The script I have written outputs all lines from the file `2` that starts with a number that  is in the file `1`.

**Question**

How do I output all the other lines that didn't matched?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @res;

open(FILE, '<', "1") or die $!;
while (defined (my $line = <FILE>)) {
  chomp $line;
  push @res, $line;
}
close FILE;

open(FILE, '<', "2") or die $!;
while (defined (my $line = <FILE>)) {
  chomp $line;
  $line =~ m/(\d+)/;

  if (defined $1) {
    foreach my $a (@res) {
      if ($a == $1) {
        print $line . "\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
close FILE;
```

File 1

```
155
156
157
158
159
160
```

File 2

```
150 a
151 f
152 r
153 a
154 a
155 a
156 a
157 f
158 f
159 f
```

Comment: Note that if your platform provides a POSIX-compatible `grep` command, you can replace your script with `grep -f1 2` and `grep -v -f1 2`. (The first if you want the current script; the second if you want [raina77ow's version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11146936/377270).)

Comment: The `defined` in `while (defined (my $line = <FILE>))` is redundant. However, the benefits of using lexical filehandles in the smallest applicable scope rather than package-global bareword filehandles are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is pretty close actually: it's enough to change this

```
foreach my $a (@res) {
  if ($a == $1) {
    print $line . "\n";
  }
}
```

... to this ...

```
my $found;
foreach my $a (@res) {
  if ($a eq $1) { # we compare strings, not numbers, even if these strings are 'numeric'
    $found = 1;
    print $line . "\n";
    last; # no need to look further, we already found an item
  }
}
print "Not matched: $line", "\n" unless $found;
```

Yet still there's something to talk about. ) See, as all these number strings in the first file are unique, it's much better to use a hash for storing them. The code will actually not change that much:

```
my %digits;
... # in the first file processing loop:
$digits{$line} = 1;
... # in the second file processing loop, instead of foreach:
if ($digits{$1}) { 
  print $line, "\n"; 
} else {
  print "Not matched: $line", "\n";
}
```

But the point is that searching in hash is MUCH faster than looping through an array again and again. )

Comment: .. are you going to talk about using a hash instead of a list?

Comment: Of course. ) This task is literally begging for hash to be introduced. )

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %res;

open(FILE, '<', "1") or die $!;
while (defined (my $line = <FILE>)) {
  chomp $line;
  $res{$line} = 1;
}
close FILE;

open(FILE, '<', "2") or die $!;
while (defined (my $line = <FILE>)) {
  if ($line =~ m/(\d+)/) {
      print $line if not $res{$1};
  }
}
close FILE;
```